# Avoid concurrent write conflicts in Cassandra

Tags: php, cassandra, cql

I'm working in a Cassandra (2.2.3) project in which I have to store reviews and make possible to get refer elements ordered for min, max, count and average of all attached reviews. For do that when I insert a new review I have to remove and re-insert the corresponding record in order to update the clustering key but for store these keys I use another table like an index. The problem is that during the update process of all these tables I use a batch but if another update process is executed in the same time I can have duplicate entries in the ordering tables or invalid values in key storage index table.

How can I make possible to execute the batch without the concurrent write risk?

Here's the tables structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS reviews (domain VARCHAR, scenario VARCHAR, refer VARCHAR, type VARCHAR, id VARCHAR, value FLOAT, comment VARCHAR, author VARCHAR, title VARCHAR, date TIMESTAMP, attributes MAP<VARCHAR, VARCHAR>, answer VARCHAR, answer_author VARCHAR, answer_title VARCHAR, answer_date TIMESTAMP, answer_attributes MAP<VARCHAR, VARCHAR>, PRIMARY KEY((domain, scenario, refer, type), id)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (id DESC);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS reviews_ext_ordering_avg (domain VARCHAR, refer VARCHAR, scenario VARCHAR, value FLOAT, type VARCHAR, PRIMARY KEY((domain, scenario, type), value, refer)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (value DESC);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS reviews_ext_ordering_min (domain VARCHAR, refer VARCHAR, scenario VARCHAR, value FLOAT, type VARCHAR, PRIMARY KEY((domain, scenario, type), value, refer)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (value ASC);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS reviews_ext_ordering_max (domain VARCHAR, refer VARCHAR, scenario VARCHAR, value FLOAT, type VARCHAR, PRIMARY KEY((domain, scenario, type), value, refer)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (value DESC);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS reviews_ext_ordering_count (domain VARCHAR, refer VARCHAR, scenario VARCHAR, value INT, type VARCHAR, PRIMARY KEY((domain, scenario, type), value, refer)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (value ASC);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS reviews_ext_index (domain VARCHAR, refer VARCHAR, scenario VARCHAR, count INT, avg FLOAT, min FLOAT, max FLOAT, sum FLOAT, type VARCHAR, PRIMARY KEY((domain, scenario, type), refer)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (refer ASC);
```

Here an example of the transaction in CQL (instead of PHP)

```
BEGIN BATCH
DELETE FROM acme_reviews_ext_ordering_avg WHERE domain = '[DOMAIN]' AND scenario = '[SCENARIO]' AND type = '[TYPE]' AND value = [VALUE] AND refer = '[REFER]';
DELETE FROM acme_reviews_ext_ordering_min WHERE domain = '[DOMAIN]' AND scenario = '[SCENARIO]' AND type = '[TYPE]' AND value = [VALUE] AND refer = '[REFER]';
DELETE FROM acme_reviews_ext_ordering_max WHERE domain = '[DOMAIN]' AND scenario = '[SCENARIO]' AND type = '[TYPE]' AND value = [VALUE] AND refer = '[REFER]';
DELETE FROM acme_reviews_ext_ordering_count WHERE domain = '[DOMAIN]' AND scenario = '[SCENARIO]' AND type = '[TYPE]' AND value = [VALUE] AND refer = '[REFER]';
INSERT INTO acme_reviews_ext_ordering_avg (domain, scenario, type, value, refer) VALUES ('[DOMAIN]', '[SCENARIO]', '[TYPE]', [VALUE], '[REFER]');
INSERT INTO acme_reviews_ext_ordering_min (domain, scenario, type, value, refer) VALUES ('[DOMAIN]', '[SCENARIO]', '[TYPE]', [VALUE], '[REFER]');
INSERT INTO acme_reviews_ext_ordering_max (domain, scenario, type, value, refer) VALUES ('[DOMAIN]', '[SCENARIO]', '[TYPE]', [VALUE], '[REFER]');
INSERT INTO acme_reviews_ext_ordering_count (domain, scenario, type, value, refer) VALUES ('[DOMAIN]', '[SCENARIO]', '[TYPE]', [VALUE], '[REFER]');
UPDATE acme_reviews_ext_index SET min = [MIN], avg = [AVG], max = [MAX], count = [COUNT], sum = [SUM] WHERE domain = '[DOMAIN]' AND scenario = '[SCENARIO]' AND type = '[TYPE]' AND refer = '[REFER]';
APPLY BATCH;
```

Here a practical example (also in CQL): A and B are two clients which insert a review in the same time, for be minimal in this case I'll update only the average: A inserts a value of 4 so the past average change from 3 to 3.5 (it's just an example), B inserts value of 4.5 and the average become 3.7 instead of past value of 3, here the two batch statements:

Here A:

```
BEGIN BATCH
DELETE FROM acme_reviews_ext_ordering_avg WHERE domain = 'foo.bar' AND scenario = 'article' AND type = 'generic' AND value = 3 AND refer = 'post-id-value';
INSERT INTO acme_reviews_ext_ordering_avg (domain, scenario, type, value, refer) VALUES ('foo.bar', 'article', 'generic', 3.5, 'refer-id-value');
UPDATE acme_reviews_ext_index SET avg = 3.5 WHERE domain = 'foo.bar' AND scenario = 'article' AND type = 'generic' AND refer = 'post-id-value';
APPLY BATCH;
```

Here B:

```
BEGIN BATCH
DELETE FROM acme_reviews_ext_ordering_avg WHERE domain = 'foo.bar' AND scenario = 'article' AND type = 'generic' AND value = 3 AND refer = 'post-id-value';
INSERT INTO acme_reviews_ext_ordering_avg (domain, scenario, type, value, refer) VALUES ('foo.bar', 'article', 'generic', 3.7, 'refer-id-value');
UPDATE acme_reviews_ext_index SET avg = 3.7 WHERE domain = 'foo.bar' AND scenario = 'article' AND type = 'generic' AND refer = 'post-id-value';
APPLY BATCH;
```

In the common case of concurrent writing A removes the row and B not because the row has been already removed by A's batch but both insert the new rows causing a duplicate, in the index table I'll have only one of key value, A or B so one of the duplicate's key value is not indexed.

I think that can also happens that when A and B batch are completed I have only one record in the ordering table, so correct, but the wrong value in the index table.

Comment: Can you add an example to your question that demonstrates your problem?  Deleting and re-inserting a record to "update the clustering key" sounds strange to me. C* does not offer isolation of batches. Assuming you cannot fix your issue by modifying the model, you need to synchronize your clients outside of C*.

Comment: Sure, I've added the batch converted from PHP into CQL, note that in PHP I use prepared statements for pass parameters. 
I saw about timestamps for batch, they can be useful in this case?

Comment: Could you use a minimal set of tables and columns as well as actual queries with values, not placeholders, to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: Yes, I've edited the post with a practical example and a minimal explaination about the issue so I hope that can be clear

Answer (score 0):

As Cassandra does not offer any isolation of transactions, I don't see how you can solve this on the C* level. You need to synchronize your clients to make sure only one has exclusive access to the table that requires a delete-insert.

The use case might also lead to problems with large number of tombstones, depending on how many deletes you have in normal operations.

Given those problems you might be better off to externalize your search for posts by value type X to an external index like Solr or ElasticSearch. OR, if you can upgrade to Cassandra 3.x, then you should be able to solve your problem with the newly introduced [materialized views](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/new-in-cassandra-3-0-materialized-views). Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32172394/cassandra-alternate-way-for-clustering-key-with-order-by-and-update) with a similar problem and a solution describing materialized views.

Comment: Why you think that an external search index may be helpful?
These problems are only in key update for ordering tables so when I create or remove a review, for read all review or values like average or count I've no problem.
About materialized views, they can be very helpful for a lot of things in my work but I can't upgrade Cassandra due to a compatibility problem of the Datastax PHP Driver which I'm using for work with Cassandra on PHP

Comment: @RyanJ, when using an external search service you should be able to drop the tables you use for ordering by avg, min, max, etc. Instead you index the values in your `acme_reviews_ext_index` table and then use the search engine to find the record IDs associated with certain values.